# Error In Speech Recognizer in Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone, speech, speech-to-text

I want to integrate speech recognition with my application.

I'm able to do it with SpeechRecognizerUI but when i creating my own UI with SpeechRecognizer it generating an exception ? Why so..
This Code always generate an exception and displays "Exception Raised".

I don't want to use SpeechRecognizerUI.

```
   private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SpeechRecognizer speechrecognizer = new SpeechRecognizer();

        try
        {
            SpeechRecognitionResult result = await speechrecognizer.RecognizeAsync();

            if (result.TextConfidence != SpeechRecognitionConfidence.Rejected)
            {
                txt.Text = result.Text;
            }


        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            int privacyPolicyHResult = unchecked((int)0x80045509);
            if (err.HResult == privacyPolicyHResult)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You will need to accept the speech privacy policy in order to use speech recognition in this app.");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Exception Raised");
            }

        }
```

Comment: The value of err.HResult would be interesting. If you have it, maybe the solution is trivial, or perhaps the exception itself provides you with some clear Message.

Answer (score 0):

Offhand, it doesn't look like you've set a recognizer with [`SpeechRecognizer.SetRecognizer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.phone.speech.recognition.speechrecognizer.setrecognizer%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).  I'm assuming you want dictation results; otherwise you'll need to set grammars, too.